# Can you navigate the contents of a Vector's index via a String?

Tags: actionscript-3, haxe

Is it possible to do something similar to this in Haxe?

```
private var _bindingsFiltered:Vector<String>;
_bindingsFiltered = new Vector<String>();

_controller_touched_binding.action = "meta_start";
```

What I would like to be able to do:

```
_bindingsFiltered[_controller_touched_binding.action] = "BUTTON_13";
trace(_bindingsFiltered["meta_start"]); //result: "BUTTON_13"
```

I want to be able to override a specific index too (still accessed via a string), with a new value, rather than keep pushing new content to the end of the vector. I have been using 'openfl.utils.Object' to cheat for now but I am looking for a more reliable approach for the long run.

**Is there a way to do this in Haxe?**

**If not, what are my options?**

I would also be interested in a solution for this in AS3, if there is one (avoiding the Array class).

**My goal is to find a method that I can use in both languages seamlessly (next-to-none, differences).**

Comment: There's a few very good answers here.. You might want to mark one of them as accepted? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this using `flash.utils.Dictionary`:

#### ActionScript

```js
import flash.utils.Dictionary;

...

var _bindingsFiltered:Dictionary = new Dictionary ();

_bindingsFiltered[_controller_touched_binding.action] = "BUTTON_13";
trace(_bindingsFiltered["meta_start"]); //result: "BUTTON_13"
```

#### Haxe

```js
import openfl.utils.Dictionary;

...

var _bindingsFiltered = new Dictionary<String, String> ();

_bindingsFiltered[_controller_touched_binding.action] = "BUTTON_13";
trace(_bindingsFiltered["meta_start"]); //result: "BUTTON_13"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I would like to iterate/loop through the list once it is populated, is that possible via the Dictionary class in both languages?

Comment: Yes, it should be similar to this: `for (key in _bindingsFiltered) { trace (key); trace (_bindingsFiltered[key]); }`

Answer (score 2):

Vector's cannot be indexed by string in Haxe. A vector is an array with a fixed size. [This is the Haxe manual on that subject.](https://haxe.org/manual/std-vector.html)

Instead of vectors, you can use a [Map.](https://haxe.org/manual/std-Map.html)

```
class Test {

    private var vector:Map<String, String> = new Map<String, String>();

    public function new() {
        var str = 'haxe';

        vector[str] = "is great";
        trace(vector[str]);
    }

    static function main() {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

https://try.haxe.org/#F74Ba

Answer (score 0):

First, do you really want an array / vector / list, or do you really want a hashmap of key / value pairs? How are you using the collection? Why do you want String keys? And related, is this mostly about access symantics (you want to type it this way), or are the runtime reasons you'd want to use strings (serialization / etc)?

From what you've described, it sounds like what you really want is an `Object` like the ones in AS3/JS/ECMAScript, with square-bracket access symantics -- `obj[key]`

Yes, you can do that in Haxe. The `openfl.utils.Object` class is a helper to do exactly this, using Dynamic objects and reflection. It should compile to exactly what you want on all Haxe targets.

In any case, if you'd like to feel like you're not bound to OpenFL, no problem. Copy the `openfl/utils/Object.hx` file and place it anywhere you like in your project's class path (and update the package statement).

There's nothing particularly OpenFL-ish about [that code](https://github.com/openfl/openfl/blob/ee092a64dbe1921fb2fc044391ee8e99ac7b2fae/openfl/utils/Object.hx). It's pure Haxe code with no dependencies. It provides array access with `String` keys, as well as `toString`, `toLocaleString`, `propertyIsEnumerable`, `iterator`, `isPrototypeOf`, and `hasOwnProperty` functions (which ECMA-folk are used to.)

The transition from AS3/JS to Haxe is a little weird, especially when it comes to dynamic objects, and I've been meaning to blog more about it. ;) Good luck!

**ETA:** In truth, you probably want to get away from Dynamic/Reflection, and embrace a more type-strict approach. AS3/JS devs don't understand this at first, but it is where the benefits of Haxe come from. If you don't then your Haxe experience is likely to be unplesant.

Comment: I plan on storing two things: A button on a controller and a made up term that will be paired with the button (both of type: String). e.g. "BUTTON_13" will be paired up with the made-up term "meta_start", this will later be used as an action trigger, to enter code blocks of any sort. If a user decides they did not like this mapping, they are free to change it on the fly, but I do not want to push and pop elements from a list that will be storing these pairs. I also later want to be able to loop/iterate through the length of the list, for exporting the pairs (mapping) to a file (of type: json).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes, you can.

```
abstract MyVector<T>(Vector<T>) {
public function new(l:Int) this = new Vector<T>(l);
@:op([]) public function set<K:T>(s:String, v:K) {
    switch (s) {
        case "FIRST": this[0] = v;
        case "SECOND": this[1] = v;
        default: return;
    }
}
@:op([]) public function get(s:String) {
    switch (s) {
        case "FIRST": return this[0];
        case "SECOND": return this[1];
        default: return cast 0;
    }
 }
```

}

```
    var mv = new MyVector<String>(2);
    mv["SECOND"] = "Second";
    trace(mv["SECOND"]); // outputs Second
```

You can inline get and set methods if you want.